# ASP .NET MySql set dateformat by default

Tags: asp.net, mysql, date-format

I'm using ASP .NET and I'm retrieving data from a MySQL S2005.

I'm using several Jquery Datepickers and I set the dateformat to: "yy/mm/dd".

However, when the datepicker's input field is filled with a date stored in the DB, it
uses different formats, depending on the language of the system.

How can I specify a default format? Should I specify this on the DB or directly on the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql uses yyyy-mm-dd.  Just convert the string to that format before inserting into the table.  If it was a typo when you said MySQL 2005 and you meant MS SQL 2005, then you will probably need to pull the date data with DATEPART. Microsoft stores their dates wierd.  There's no telling what you will pull out of the database if you just pull the value of the datefield itself.

Query for 
DATEPART ( dd, datefield )
DATEPART ( yyyy, datefield )
DATEPART ( mm, datefield)

then put it together however you want.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL you use DATEFORMAT:

```
declare @MyTable Table([date] datetime)

SET DATEFORMAT ymd
Insert into @MyTable values ('14/1/2')
select * from @MyTable
```

Generally, in DATEFORMAT you place 'y', 'm' and 'd' in any sequence you need